# Solve a system of differential equations where argument of one function depend at another argument

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve a system of differential equations using Mathcad.

Moreover, the condition argument of one function depends on $t$, and delated $y = t - t_0$.

How make a substitution argument in the function $ N(y) $?

[image]
Editor's comment: Class of coupled / delayed differential equations.

Comment: In your cited image it is $N(t)$?

Comment: It's N(y) where y=t-t0

Answer (score 0):

Set $M(t)=N(t-t_0)$, then you have a boundary value problems with linear boundary conditions at $t=0$ and $t=t_0$.

---

Resulting system

```
a*R'(t)+b*R''(t) = R(t)*(c-d*R(t)+e*M(t)),  R(0) = R0,   R'(0) = DR0,
a*M'(t)+b*M''(t) = M(t)*(f-g*M(t)+h*R(t)),  M(t0) = N0,  M'(t0) = DN0.
```

or with the constants as supplied by timyrik20

[image: boundary value problem]

---

Now you can try to use ODEsolve in some versions of MathCad (15 but not Prime? by topics in the [community forum](https://community.ptc.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?location=forum-board:PTCMathcad&q=odesolve%20boundary)). Single or multiple shooting strategies are usually employed in this case. Basically, the initial conditions of $M$ at $t=0$ are introduced as variables, the integration process can be reduced to a function to the values of the other boundary, where the boundary conditions form a non-linear system. This can be solved via Newton or derivative free (adjoint) secant methods. This single shooting approach seems to be used by MathCad, or you can emulate it by explicitly employing the solver on a parametrized solution. Other answers in the forum employ the MathCad command line with additional specialized procedures,...

Comment: Whether I have understood you, when t0=3
http://i.stack.imgur.com/nl5H8.png

Comment: Yes, like that, apart from the arguments of Odesolve, check the documentation, the second argument should be `t0` or a somewhat larger constant, the last can be omitted, 10 subdivisions could be too small.